# ViewModel property being painted as literal text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am a bit new to razor.  So for the below, it's showing model.CarModelName as literal text instead of rendering the value for CarModelName

```
<p>Cars for for model.CarModelName </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the proper *Razor Syntax*:

```
<p>Cars for for @Model.CarModelName </p>
```

---

**Quick Reference**

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: thanks previous to posting this thread, I was using lowercase and actually had tried putting the @ in front of lowercase m instead of uppercase like you have it

Comment: @CoffeeAddict yep, that'll do it ... `Model` is a property of the `WebViewPage<T>` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try @model.CarModelName.  That denotes code that needs to be executed instead of just text.